# Expect script error- extra characters after close-quote

Tags: shell-script, scripting, expect, tcl

Error while executing  send if command, Not sure if I'm missing some tcl syntax.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# Get the list of hosts, one per line #####
set f [open "/tmp/host.txt"]
set hosts [read $f]
close $f

# Iterate over the hosts
foreach host $hosts {
spawn ssh $host
expect "password: "
send "abcd@123\r"
expect "$ "
send "if [ `df -Ph / | grep -vE '^Filesystem' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' |cut -d'%' -f1` -ge 60 ] ;then  echo "Hi Team- Please check root file system space on `hostname` " | mailx -s "Alert: Almost out of disk space on `hostname`" zoom@oracle.com ;fi\r" 
expect "$ " 
send "exit\r" 
expect eof     }
```

---

*===Error===*

```
[root@hzavks01~]# extra characters after close-quote
    while executing
"send "if [ `df -Ph / | grep -vE '^Filesystem' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' |cut -d'%' -f1` -ge 60 ] ;then  echo "Hi Team- Please check root file system..."
    ("foreach" body line 6)
    invoked from within
"foreach host $hosts {
spawn ssh $host
expect "password: "
send "abcd@123\r"
expect "$ "
send "if [ `df -Ph / | grep -vE '^Filesystem' | awk '{ print $5..."
    (file "./test.sh" line 10)
```

Comment: The string that you use with `send` seems to contain double quotes. I'm not sure what `expect` does with double-quoted strings that contain double quotes, but a guess is that you would have to escape the internal ones as `\"`.

Comment: I tried escaping all the internal "  but didn't fixed. I guess missing some syntax for escaping characters in tcl

Comment: instead of `send "...\r"` write `send {...}; send "\r"` (that is, put everything in braces instead of double quotes, except for the CR, which you send separately). Otherwise, `tcl` will also try to expand the `$5` and `$1` from the awk command, even if you try to escape the double quotes inside `"..."`.

Comment: and if you use braces `{...}` instead of double quotes `"..."`, do **not** escape `"` as `\"`.

Comment: Tcl/Expect syntax is quite tricky. take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with shell code only.

Answer (score 3):

[TCL is simple](https://www.tcl.tk/about/language.html). In this case as `mosvy` indicates in the comments use `{...}` to disable interpolation of the tricky shell code. However the `\r` to input the command must not be escaped, and the `send` procedure wants a single string, so either join the string together or use two `send` calls:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
catch {exec rm foo}
log_file expect.log
spawn -noecho sh
expect -ex {$ }
send {df | awk '/\//{print $NF}' > foo}
send "\r"
expect -ex {$ }
send -- {exit}
send "\r"
expect eof
```

This might be improved on with a `sendline` procedure for the task that keeps the `\r` bit from cluttering up the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
proc sendline {line} { send -- "$line\r" }
spawn -noecho sh
expect -ex {$ }
sendline {df | awk '/\//{print $NF}' > foo}
expect -ex {$ }
sendline "exit"
expect eof
```

If you do need interpolation then backwhacking will be necessary, though in that case it might be better to eliminate the shell code and instead call a program directly on the remote system that performs the necessary task or produces the necessary output in an easy to consume form.

Comment: Very clean solution.

Comment: very good answer! I wish you or someone else could have made an answer like this one [on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640935/prevent-expect-from-hanging-when-running-through-ssh) [some](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640793/send-ctrlc-to-script-running-through-ssh) [other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640396/automating-vncserver-with-expect-not-working-as-expected) related questions I made ;)

Answer (score 1):

I got mine working by setting the username and password at the start of script.

`set Username "END_USER"`

Imagine my password was `pas\Sw)/ord`

I had to set the special characters in hex, where hex for

`\` is `\x5c`

`)` is `\x29`

`/` is `\x2f`

So I had to set it in using the syntax below without `"` at the beginning and `"` at the end.

`set Password pas\x5cSw\x29\x2ford`

hex values can be found at http://defindit.com/ascii.html

You can also use

`puts "$Username"`

`puts $Password`

to echo the values for verification purpose.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to clarify  what is part of the `code` and what isn't? Thanks.

Comment: It works for me.