# Ignore SIGHUP with trap while still being able to receive output and send input

Tags: signals, trap

So i already know one can ignore HUP by doing:

```
trap "command" HUP
```

but since that completely background the process, is it possible to do the same but still being able to send input to said command? (without using possible alternative like `screen`, `tmux` etc)

If it was, this could be used as an alternative to post like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640396/automating-vncserver-with-expect-not-working-as-expected) one (where `screen` is used as a solution).

Eg:

```bsh
trap "echo HUP received" HUP; read X; echo input was $X
```

This works, but only for *sending* input. It doesn't show it's output, thus limiting usage if the process that was used with `trap` is interactive (ncurse, etc).

So if one wanted to use `trap` on a command (to ignore HUP), and automate some task with `expect` (which need output):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

read -s PWD

/usr/bin/expect -d <<EOF
set timeout -1
spawn trap "/usr/bin/vncserver -geometry 1366x768 :1" HUP
expect "Password:"
send "$PWD\r"
expect "Verify:"
send "$PWD\r"
expect "Would you like to enter a view-only password"
send "n\r"
expect eof
EOF
```

That wouldn't work. (unless alternative such as `screen`, `tmux` etc were used)

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want to achieve. Can you elaborate what you mean by "completely background the process" and which command is "said command"?

Comment: @berndbausch I mean exactly what i meant... If you tried the trap command above, you'll notice that it background the process "completely", and if said command that was "trapped" is what you would call "interactive" (ncurse, passwd, etc) then you wouldn't be able to normally send input to it, unless you would use alternative such as tmux, screen, etc.

Comment: what i want to achieve then, is clear given what i said in my post, which is to say, use trap to make a process ignore HUP signal, while still being able to send input to it (without using alternative like screen, tmux etc) @berndbausch

Comment: This script runs fine in the foreground: `trap "echo HUP received" HUP; read X; echo input was $X`. You may want to add your code to the question.

Comment: @berndbausch your command just hang indefinitely on my end... (tried it on bash)

Comment: It's waiting for your input. In the foreground.

Comment: oh, yeah i see what you mean. Guess I'll edit my post real quick :) @berndbausch

Comment: Disclaimer: I know very little about `expect`. However, `spawn` creates a new process, and the `trap` only works for this new process, not for the expect program as a whole. I see that `expect` has its own `trap` command; perhaps you should use that?

Comment: Never thought of checking the `trap` command from `expect`. Will try it and edit/post answer accordingly, thanks @berndbausch

Comment: `couldn't execute "trap": no such file or directory while executing "spawn trap "/usr/bin/vncserver -geometry 1366x768 :1" HUP"` – You cannot spawn a shell *bultin* this way. If you don't get this error then possibly you have `trap` as an *external executable*. It's a mystery what it does. It cannot do what the builtin does. You can however spawn a shell script that uses the builtin, I believe.

Comment: I see. That explain why it didn't work on my end. Thanks for trying and reporting :D @KamilMaciorowski

Comment: Note I don't know if `trap` inside a spawned shell script will work as you want. I only know it will be *the* `trap` builtin. Following "`expect` has its own `trap` command; perhaps you should use that" seems a good idea.