# Send Ctrl+C to script running through ssh

Tags: ssh, terminal, expect

So i got a script that i run through ssh like so:

```bsh
ssh user@ip <<'EOF'
export TERM=xterm
#list of commands here
EOF
```

Problem is, in certain instance, i need to use `Ctrl`+`C` in the terminal, mainly when running application such as `expect` or other that could use prompt or ncurse...

I know i could do something like this:

```bsh
commandhere
PID=$!
kill -INT $PID
```

But that wouldn't be right in this case, since i would either need to:

- use a function (prefer to only use a list of command like above, plus it wouldn't run locally but instead through ssh as far as i know)
- use this after each command.

How could i send `Ctrl`+`C` on the current terminal when running commands through ssh?

Comment: probably it's best fo not use this patern of `ssh << heredoc`

Comment: Why? When the heredoc is quoted (as it is here), it's a safe and effective way to send some text to the stdin of a program.

Comment: yeah, and i wouldn't want to use a temp file and use `scp`, since that's less dynamic/useful for small script IMO

Comment: If you are editing the script with `emacs` you can type a literal C-c by first typing C-q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You send a Ctrl-C with

```
send -- \x03
```