# Send keypress to non-GUI program

Tags: ssh, stdin

I try to manipulate `ssh` process by another process.
Image i run `ssh root@XXXX` and the pid is 12345. I want to run a program to tell the ssh session to run `ls` command, i tried `echo ls > /proc/12345/fd/0`. the ssh terminal shows the echo correctly, but after i press `enter`, the remote machine seems like it doesn't receive `ls` command.

Is there anything to do what i want?

to be more specificly, the server i tried to log in uses dynamic password, neither public nor password of standard ssh authentication method. The server prompt to input otp and authenticate

Comment: I listed different options in my answer. Do let me know if any of these work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There four methods that comes to mind:

- tmux
- ssh
- expect
- other methods

## Tmux

Using `tmux`, you can send string or key presses to a panes where `ssh` might be running/could be set to run:

```bsh
tmux new -d -s mySession
tmux send-keys -t mySession.0 "ssh root@XXXX" ENTER
tmux send-keys -t mySession.0 "ls" ENTER
```

Your mileage may vary depending on how many times it take to connect or if there a password/key to use, but that's probably obvious here.

## Ssh

This one is maybe not so obvious, but there roughly two ways to run commands through ssh directly:

- Using shell commands directly

```bsh
ssh remote "command here"
```

or

```bsh
ssh -t remote "command here"
```

- Using heredoc with ssh

```bsh
ssh remote << 'EOF' # can use any other marker pair/string as explained below
command
list
here
EOF
```

This one give you more freedom in what you can run, and is less of a hassle to handle quotes here too.

One problem is that you'll need to either use syntax highlighting when making the heredoc in [your text editor here] so that you can see if the `heredoc` marker are closed properly, especially if the said marker appear in whatever string you use in your heredoc...(or just use a longer heredoc marker, that work too)

You can use both of these depending on what you want to do, but do know this:

- It will spawn one PID per ssh process on your remote machine, so if you want to run multiple commands in succession and decide that you want to separate them in different lines or heredoc, then you will run out of PIDs at some point (if this is a restricted VM/Machine, or if you are low on resources on your remote).
- Just make sure to handle closing them/leaving only one left so you can still leave a ssh connection going if you want.
- Either of those solution might complain about `TERM` variable not being set, just set it like this:

```bsh
export TERM=xterm
```

## Expect

You can use expect, as other answer mentioned:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh remote.server.com
expect "password: "
send "passwordhere?\r"
expect "$ "
......       ##Various automated commands##
expect "$ "
send "exit\r"
```

Your mileage will vary *a lot more* here, given `expect` is kind of [hit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640935/prevent-expect-from-hanging-when-running-through-ssh) [or](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640793/send-ctrlc-to-script-running-through-ssh) [miss](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640396/automating-vncserver-with-expect-not-working-as-expected), especially when it comes to interacting with password prompts...

## Others Methods

You can use others methods, such as the following:

- `sendkeys` from [this](https://github.com/kyoto/sendkeys) repo, or/and `xdotool` from your local repo can send keys/string to particular windows, which could be set to a terminal running `ssh` or whatever you may choose. Below is the (example) syntax for both.

```bsh
sendkey.sh "Yourwindowname" "yourstringorkey"
```

or/and

```bsh
xdotool type --window "window ID here" "your string here"
```

Note:

Sometimes, `xdotool` and/or `sendkey` may work or not on different windows/programs, but both should works on most Terminal.

If one doesn't work, try the other one. Additionally, `wmctrl` should probably be installed too to get the id/pid/info of the window(s) you're targeting, unless you prefer to use `xprop` for that...(which is already installed on most distribution).

Lastly, you could one of these:

- `evdev` (thanks to @Forest for mentioning this)
- `pyinput`
- `pyautogui`

Those three are mainly used as python library, though also ported over to other langs...This would make this answer too long if i were to cover this here, so I'll let someone else do that in their own answer.

Comment: to be more specific, the server i tried to login uses a non-standard authentication method, netheir public nor password, but prompt for inputing dynamic password like otp(one time password). and the prompt is from server.                     so ssh doesn't work, xdotool doesn't work because it requires my screen on. i don't know why tmux and expect works but server always say "wrong password". since the server doesn't echo password so i have no idea what when wrong

Comment: OK, tmux works. i just need to sleep before send keys. However expect doesn't work. I don't know why

Comment: evdev requires root, i think it's the last option

Comment: well, I did mentioned your mileage will vary a lot more when using `expect` (had to struggle with it a couple times before) :) Does that mean you managed to make it work with any of the options I mentioned?

Comment: tmux works, ssh doesn't work, xdtool works but requires X11, expect doesn't work

Comment: I see. Does that mean you solved it using `tmux` since it's working, or is there some problem with it? feel free to give feedback :) @demonguy

Answer (score -2):

No. By design, processes don't work that way on Unix/Linux.

The `expect` program might be of some help, if I understand what you want. Read `man expect`.

Comment: This is incorrect. You can do it through evdev which nearly all systems have.

Comment: didn't know about `evdev`, Nice :D @forest