# Prevent expect from hanging when running through ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, vnc, expect

Based on another [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/640409/409852)'s answer, i managed to make `expect` automate `vncserver` through ssh (optionally on a chroot in this case), like so:

```bsh
ssh user@ip "rm ~/.vnc/passwd"
echo -n "`PASS_VNC`" | ssh user@ip "cat > PASS_VNC.file"
ssh user@ip << 'EOF'
export TERM=xterm
chroot /targetdir
PWD="$( cat PASS_VNC.file )"
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
set timeout -1
spawn screen bash
send -- "/usr/bin/vncserver -geometry 1366x768 :1\r"
expect "Password:"
send -- "$PWD\r"
expect "Verify:"
send -- "$PWD\r"
expect "Would you like to enter a view-only password"
send -- "n\r"
expect eof
EOD
EOF
```

That *work*, both for setting up the password (generated by another function called `PASS_VNC`, which i save in a file on the remote machine) + launching `vncserver` successfully...problem is, it *hang* (when the expect script finish), and I'm always obliged to use `Ctrl`+`C` *manually*.

I tried everything i could think of, whether it's using `exit` in the expect script, `close` (part of expect), `sleep`, `send -- \x03` (for sending `Ctrl`+`C`), etc.

I'm unsure how to prevent the hanging. How could i do this in this specific instance? I'm guessing the hanging might come from either `expect eof` or `set timeout -1`, but if those are removed, then the script wouldn't work right, at least in my own testing.

Using `-t` with ssh doesn't help much if at all (same result).

PS: I prefer to not send a script over `scp` and prefer this method of using `ssh` with an heredoc if possible.

Comment: The problem is that the expect script appears to *never* finish: you spawn a shell in screen, launch vnc, but never exit from screen. What happens after you give "n" to "Would you like to enter a view-only password"? Do you get back to a bash prompt?

Comment: Yeah, i do go back to a bash prompt, although it is only "visually" so, and by using the key combination `Ctrl`+`C`, it go back to my local prompt... @glennjackman

Comment: Essentially, `expect script finish on remote` -> `hang on (visual) remote bash prompt` -> `key combo Ctrl+C` -> `return to local bash prompt` is what happen. Otherwise, everything the script does _work_.

Comment: The "clean" way to do it would be: expect the bash prompt, send "exit", **then** expect eof. Or, if you want to keep the screen session running, when you see the bash prompt, send `Ctrl+A` (`\x01`) then `d` to detach

Comment: But i heard it's hard to expect to bash prompt, unless you either know what it is in advance or set it to a temp one? would love if you have some code example that i could work with :) @glennjackman

Comment: My prompts usually end with a dollar sign and a space, so `expect -re {\$ $}` works for me. Or, after you spawn bash, do something like `send "PS1='>'\r"` so you know exactly what to expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! Though that didn't work, that did force me to try a bunch of other setting from `expect`, which lead me to a solution :D @glennjackman

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out some things, found something that work:

```bsh
ssh user@ip "rm ~/.vnc/passwd"
echo -n "`PASS_VNC`" | ssh user@ip "cat > PASS_VNC.file"
ssh user@ip << 'EOF'
export TERM=xterm
chroot /targetdir
PWD="$( cat PASS_VNC.file )"
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
set timeout -1
spawn screen bash
send -- "/usr/bin/vncserver -geometry 1366x768 :1\r"
expect "Password:"
send -- "$PWD\r"
expect "Verify:"
send -- "$PWD\r"
expect "Would you like to enter a view-only password"
send -- "n\r"
interact
EOD
EOF
```

Seems like replacing `expect eof` with `interact` work better. It doesn't hang, set the password right, and even launch it correctly.